# How can I get numbers from iwidgets.interact?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, interactive

I wrote a simple .ipynb for iwidget.interactive practice:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
@widgets.interact( number1=20, number2=30)
def sum_or_prod(number1, number2):
    s_2 = number1+number2
    p_2 = number1*number2
    if p_2 < 1000:
        print('The result is sum: ' + str(s_2))
    else:
        print('The result is product: ' + str(p_2))
```

How could I get `number1`, `number2` if I change the slider?

Answer (score 0):

If by getting `number1` and `number2` you mean displaying their updated values after moving the sliders, you can simply print their values the same way you did with your product and sum. The code then looks like that:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
@widgets.interact( number1=20, number2=30)
def sum_or_prod(number1, number2):
    s_2 = number1+number2
    p_2 = number1*number2
    if p_2 < 1000:
        print('The result is sum: ' + str(s_2))
    else:
        print('The result is product: ' + str(p_2))
    print('Number 1: '+str(number1))
    print('Number 2: '+str(number2))
```

And the variables `number1` and `number2` will change values as you move the sliders.
An example of the output of this code can be seen below:

[image]